# catchup problem of the ledger in captive-core

Tags: stellar-core

I want to sync the block data and query all transaction data. When we execute the captive core server, It starts to download and catch up the ledger file by stellar-core automatically.
The data is stored in /tmp/captive-stellar-coreXXX. Is that right? and why are you doing this?

Finally, I want you to tell me how to sync XLM block using captive-core. Thanks.

Captive Core Server Error log:

```
ERRO[2021-03-11T16:52:14.824+09:00] default: Exception occurred while shutting down: sqlite3_statement_backend::prepare: no such table: storestate  pid=2450 subservice=stellar-core
ERRO[2021-03-11T16:52:14.827+09:00] default: Got an exception: bind: Address already in use  pid=2450 subservice=stellar-core
```

Here's the reference data.

```
ps -ef | grep stellar-core
1. /home/stellar/bin/stellar-core --conf /tmp/captive-stellar-core695861656/stellar-core.conf catchup 4498561/99968 --metadata-output-stream fd:3 --replay-in-memory
2. curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/ledger/00/43/29/ledger-004329ff.xdr.gz -o /tmp/captive-stellar-core695861656/buckets/tmp/catchup-880e8b173d3467bb/ledger/00/43/29/ledger-004329ff.xdr.gz.tmp

[version]
horizon: v2.0.0
stellar-core: v1.15.1

[environment variables]
CAPTIVE_CORE_CONFIG_APPEND_PATH="/home/stellar/bin/stellar-captive-core-stub.toml"
DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:_password_@localhost/horizon"
NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"
STELLAR_CORE_DATABASE_URL="postgres://postgres:_password_@localhost/stellar"
STELLAR_CORE_URL="http://localhost:8080"
```

Here are the setting files. (stellar-core.cfg, stellar-captive-core-stub.toml)

```
[stellar-core.cfg]
LOG_FILE_PATH="/home/stellar/logs/stellar-core.log"
BUCKET_DIR_PATH="/home/stellar/buckets" 

HTTP_PORT=8080
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true
PEER_PORT=11625

DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar host=localhost user=stellar password=XXX"

#FAILURE_SAFETY is minimum number of nodes that are allowed to fail before you no longer have quorum
FAILURE_SAFETY=1

# number of ledgers to synchronize (time in seconds divided by 5)
# NB: full validators should run with CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true instead
CATCHUP_COMPLETE=true 
#CATCHUP_RECENT=60480

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015"

TARGET_PEER_CONNECTIONS=16 

# Populate NODE_NAMES, KNOW_PEERS, QUORUM and HISTORY sections with information
# on other validators
# for example https://github.com/stellar/docs/blob/master/validators.md
# or from https://dashboard.stellar.org/
NODE_NAMES=[
"GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH  sdf_watcher1",
"GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK  sdf_watcher2",
"GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ  sdf_watcher3",
]

KNOWN_PEERS=[
"core-live-a.stellar.org",
"core-live-b.stellar.org",
"core-live-c.stellar.org",
]

UNSAFE_QUORUM=true

[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=51
VALIDATORS=[
"$sdf_watcher1", "$sdf_watcher2", "$sdf_watcher3"
]

# Stellar.org history store
[HISTORY.core_live_001]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.core_live_002]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[HISTORY.core_live_003]
get="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"


[stellar-captive-core-stub.toml]

[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
QUALITY="HIGH"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_1"
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH"
ADDRESS="core-live-a.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_2"
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK"
ADDRESS="core-live-b.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_3"
HOME_DOMAIN="www.stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ"
ADDRESS="core-live-c.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

---

Thanks for the reply @Terence Rokop, @Bartek Nowotarski

*@Terence Rokop*

When I first started the stellar-core(`run` command) and second I ran Horizon ingestion(`serve` command), another stellar-core process is running using config file In /tmp directory "automatically". So I encountered the following bind error. and the meaning of "sync XLM block" is same to "perform a Horizon ingestion"

The process for another stellar-core is following there.

```
/home/stellar/bin/stellar-core --conf /tmp/captive-stellar-core495000143/stellar-core.conf run --in-memory --start-at-ledger 34392894 --start-at-hash 9b4a5166fbf227713a5920c753bfc5840311f71860ffc9babdb9731d69467136 --metadata-output-stream fd:3  
curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/transactions/00/9e/a3/transactions-009ea37f.xdr.gz -o /home/stellar/buckets/tmp/catchup-8bff4e3262733811/transactions/00/9e/a3/transactions-009ea37f.xdr.gz.tmp
```

*@Bartek Nowotarski*

My environment is here. Is there a problem?

```
STELLAR_CORE_URL='http://localhost:8080'
REMOTE_CAPTIVE_CORE_URL='http://localhost:8001'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the following...

```
ERRO[2021-03-11T16:52:14.824+09:00] default: Exception occurred while shutting down: sqlite3_statement_backend::prepare: no such table: storestate  pid=2450 subservice=stellar-core
ERRO[2021-03-11T16:52:14.827+09:00] default: Got an exception: bind: Address already in use  pid=2450 subservice=stellar-core
```

...usually means that I've tried to start a `stellar-core` instance when there's already one running, although I'm not sure from the log/config excerpts why that might be happening in this case (or whether that's definitely what *is* happening).

By "sync XLM block" do you mean "perform a Horizon ingestion"?

Comment: is right. We are planning to allow changing the peer port to other value. Tracking this here: https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/3441.

Comment: I edited additional information for your comment in my question. please check my question again, thanks.

Comment: @BoohyungLee It looks to me as though that matches the description of the issue -- Bartek might know whether there's a workaround before https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/3441 is resolved; I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved the problems.